# How to add to the object of SelectManyCheckbox selected values?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have an object of SelectManyCheckbox. For this object I set available values in the next way:

```
SelectManyCheckbox checkbox = new SelectManyCheckbox();

List<Double> selected = new ArrayList<Double>();//this will be used for setting selected values
List<SelectItem> items = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();//this will be used as available values

for (SomeObject av : listOfObjects)
            {
                SelectItem item = new SelectItem(av.getNumericValue(),
                        av.getValue());
                items.add(item);
                if (av.getDefault())
                {
                    selected.add(av.getNumericValue());
                }
            }

UISelectItems uiItems = new UISelectItems();
uiItems.setValue(items);
checkbox.getChildren().add(uiItems);
checkbox.setSelectedValues(new Double[selected.size()]);
```

But this way of setting of selected values does not work. Maybe someone know there is the source of the problem?

Comment: Your Double[] is empty there, try converting the list to the array like this: `checkbox.setSelectedValues(selected.toArray(new Double[selected.size()]));`

Comment: oh, on a long way of editting I lost this code=( Thanks=)I'm sooo inattentive

Comment: Oh ok, I suggested you to create a new question because I thought it was a bigger problem, but fortunately it was simpler :). You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Double[] is empty there, try converting the list to the array like this:

```
checkbox.setSelectedValues(selected.toArray(new Double[selected.size()]));
```